# Using template in complex list variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I have a var file like below and the two items don't work the same: the first one is treated as a JSON object and I can access its properties, such as `script.name`, but it's not the case for the second item which seems to be a plain string.

How can I define the second element of the list in such a way that I can access its properties?

```
---

file2: script2.j2

scripts_list:
  - { name: script1, file: script1.j2 }
  - "{ name: script2, file: {{ file2 }} }"
```

---

More details - I use the list in a loop like this:

```
# main.yml

- include_tasks: script.yml
  loop: "{{ scripts_list }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: script

# script.yml

- debug:
    msg: "loop variable = {{ script }}"

- debug:
    msg: "loop variable name = {{ script.name }}"
```

The first item in the list works fine, but the second returns an error when accessing its `name` property.

The output seems to show that the first item is treated as a JSON structure whereas the second is just a plain string:

```
TASK [test : debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test] => {
    "msg": "loop variable = {u'name': u'script1', u'file': u'script1.j2'}"
}

TASK [test : debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test] => {
    "msg": "loop variable name = script1"
}

TASK [test : debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test] => {
    "msg": "loop variable = { name: script2, file: script2.j2 }"
}

TASK [test : debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [test]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'name'\n"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I define the second element of the list in such a way that I can access its properties?

Well IMO the best way to address this since you are defining your scripts info inside a yaml file is to use a yaml definition for all of them and to quote elements with jinja2 templating appropriately.

```
scripts_list:
  - name: script1
    file: script1.j2
  - name: script2
    file: "{{ file2 }}"
```

If for some reason you want to keep the jsonish definition, the following should work as expected:

```
scripts_list:
  - { name: script1, file: script1.j2 }
  - { name: script2, file: "{{ file2 }}" }
```

Comment: Aaargh - didn't think of putting the quotes just around the template like you did in your second example. It works as expected, perfect.